# Export LAS file to XYZ and retain RGB values

Tags: qgis, lidar, xyz, point-cloud, lastools

I am currently trying to import LAZ LIDAR data into ArchiCAD (a 3D modeling software) for an architectural project. Using QGIS 3.22.11 and LAStools las2txt I have successfully exported the LAZ file as an XYZ file (which is what ArchiCAD needs). However, during the export process the point could data is losing the RGB color values and is rendering in ArchiCAD as all black.

Is there a way to export the data and retain the RGB color values?

Comment: Please post a link to your data.

Comment: Here is google drive link to one of the laz files I am working with.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W9EuWdpcoRZpZv9Ww3VCR2NrBcYH5bS0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think "the colors are wrongly coded in the LAS file". Read [Here](https://danielgm.net/cc/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2652). I had no luck in either CloudCompare or FugroViewer.
  "Color R 0 65280

        G 0 65280

        B 0 65280"

Comment: I see, thank you for checking. Nothing to do then if the LAS file was written wrong from the start?